# 301 Rewrite Redirection causes double Slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

My standard domain is https://example.com/ so everything else should be redirected there.

- http://example.com/ --> https://example.com/
- http://www.example.com/ --> https://example.com/
- https://www.example.com/ --> https://example.com/

I use this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately, when going to http://example.com/ or http://www.example.com/ I get redirected to https://example.com//

Any ideas how to remove the double slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `/` before `%{REQUEST_URI}` in target.

You can actually do this in a single rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Test this in a new browser or clear browser cache.